# How to add files to uploadify from code?

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) but I need to incorporate a drag'n drop module for the browsers that support this feature.

Right now the only way to select files is via the browser dialog window. I'd like to have something like:

```
$("mySelector").uploadify("addFile",{src:...; name:...; etc:...});
```

This would allow me to get the paths of the files dropped into the browser add them to the upload queue. Is there any way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a few months of research it turns out that the file implementation of flash is incompatible with the file implementation of HTML5 that starts to be supported by more and more browsers.

In other words, for security reasons, there is not bridge for sending file objects between the languages.

One research idea would be to implement such a bridge, but that is a discussion for another time. Uploadify 2.x does not support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

**Note:**
Uploading files are only possible from file-type-input (browser dialog window), for security reasons. You cannot read path from file-type-input. Not even using JS. Nor you can write the path to a file-type-input.

The plugins like mentioned above, are the UX tricks but all are limited to this security constraint of using file-type-input for uploads. Else, you need something in the line of Flash, ActiveX uploaders, etc that provide queue uploads.

Comment: I gave that on a try today, it does not support multiple file selection in IE, and since I can drag and drop file for it, without the need to immediately upload them, then I don't see how come this is not possible with uploadify. The only reason I'm trying to stick with uploadify is for the IE support.

Comment: I gave http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload another try. So far I've seen that we can't drop file in IE. Neither can we select multiple files. This is really a draw back as over 70% of the targeted users have IE7-9.